# override link style inside an html div

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, stylesheet

I have a div in which I'd like to override my global link style. I have two link styles, one global, one specific. Here the code:

```
A:link {text-decoration: none; color: #FF0000;}
A:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #FF0000;}
A:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #FF0000;}
A:active {text-decoration: none; color: #FF0000;}

#macrosectiontext
{
    position:relative;
    font:Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:50px;
    font-style: bold;
    margin-top:245px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-color:transparent;
}

#macrosectiontext A:link {text-decoration: none; color: #000000;}
#macrosectiontext A:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
#macrosectiontext A:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
#macrosectiontext A:active {text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
```

and I use the div like this:

```
<div id="macrosectiontext"><a href="www.google.it">bla bla bla</a></div>
```

however it seems that it doesn't work. The div still inherits the global link style.

Comment: I'm not seeing an anchor link in your HTML

Comment: Just write `#macrosectiontext a {color:#000000};` this will work

Comment: Works fine for me. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xz8KQ/).

Comment: @Paulie_D: I forgot to add the anchor link... here it is

Comment: Yep, JSFiddle mentioned above would seem to confirm it should be working. Perhaps you have a spelling error somewhere?

Comment: it doesn't work. I have a global link redefinition rule in my css file. I've added it to the question above

Comment: think this => a !== A

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. In The css I would not use the id "#macrosectiontext a:link..." for the link code I would use a class ".macrosectiontext"
2. use a lower case "a" instead of a Cap "A" in the link style
3. If you using the style only a few times you can use a span tag around the link and then call to your style from the span tag in stead of the div.

Comment: The first point mentioned is the key.  assign a class for the link and define the color inside the class. cool!

Answer (score 15):

CSS work on inheritance, so you should only override the properties you want to change.

Try always to write HTML & CSS lowercase, still your HTML and CSS are correct

```
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #f00;
}

#macrosectiontext {
  position: relative;
  font:Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-style: bold;
  margin-top: 245px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#macrosectiontext a:link {
  color: #000;
}
#macrosectiontext a:visited,
#macrosectiontext a:hover,
#macrosectiontext a:active {
  color: #fff;
}
```

I [made a fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/3jCBQ/) to show your code is working (*changed the hover color, just for demo*)